# getline(file,array) isn't moving to the next line

Tags: c++, getline

I've looked at the other getline questions and couldn't come up with a solution. I will have a file formatted like so:

```
book
author
book
author
...
```

The code is to read the book title into the struct at book.name, and then the author at book.author but what I am getting is a blank for book and only author is printing. I know it's overwriting book.name but I'm not sure how to remedy it.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Books {
   string name;
   string author;
};

Books books[100];


int main(){
   fstream file;
   file.open("test.txt");

   while(!file.eof()){
      getline(file,books[0].name);
      getline(file,books[0].author);
   }
   file.close();
   cout << books[0].name << " " << books[0].author << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

update: works with vectors now, too, though I've not been able to get it as fancy as the answer below, this is at least a bit more understandable for my level of C++ at the moment.

```
struct book_meta_data {
  string name;
  string author;
};
int i = 0;
book_meta_data b;
while ( getline(f,b.name) && getline(f,b.author) &&
      ++i){
        books.push_back(b);
      }

cout << books.size() << endl;
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != books.size(); i++){
  cout << books[i].name << " " << books[i].author << endl;
}
```

Comment: See [why `while(!file.eof())` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
while(!file.eof()){
   getline(file,books[0].name);
   getline(file,books[0].author);
}
```

to

```
int i = 0;
while(getline(file,books[i].name) && getline(file,books[i].author) && ++i < 100);
```

Comment: @AlexandarNarayan [Some context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: could it work with a vector?   say a vector<Books> v; ?

Comment: @AlexandarNarayan Sure. But you should have a separate variable to gain input, and use `push_back()` inside of the `while()` loop.